# getting error null pointer exception attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

getting error that null pointer exception has occurred and trying to invoke virtual method

```
public class after10th extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.after10th);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchten);
        ArrayList<String> after_ten = new ArrayList<>();
        after_ten.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.after_ten)));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(after10th.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, after_ten);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menusearchten);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`enter code here`
    }

}
```

This is the error:

09-23 19:09:17.242 9000-9000/com.example.supriya.career_guidance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.supriya.career_guidance, PID: 9000

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says outright that `item.getActionView()` returns null, on this line:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
```